# i created service, but it shows inactive (dead)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu, systemctl

this is not the same problem as other topics have. i was trying to create a service on my ubuntu but it keep saying this service is inactive (dead).

**my OS**:

[image]

**my service** (at  /etc/systemd/system/resume.service ):

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Run commands after resume from suspend
After=suspend.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/resume.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

**my shell script** (at /usr/local/bin/resume.sh ):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Workaround for XFCE bug re black screen on resume from suspend:
# if a user is logged into an X session via xfce, run 'xrandr --auto' to restore default display.

for id in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
    s="$(loginctl show-session "$id")"
    if printf "$s" | grep -q 'Display=:0'
    then
        if printf "$s" | grep -q 'Desktop=xfce'
        then
            u="$(printf "$s" | grep 'Name=' | cut -d'=' -f2)"
            DISPLAY=:0 su "$u" -c 'xrandr --auto'
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
```

i tried **these commands** but i couldnt activate the service:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable resume.service
sudo systemctl start resume.service
```

**after i run $sudo systemctl status resume.service** :

```bash
○ resume.service - Run commands after resume from suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/resume.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: inactive (dead)

سپتامبر 15 22:59:00 linux systemd[1]: resume.service: Deactivated successfull>
سپتامبر 15 22:59:30 linux systemd[1]: Started Run commands after resume from >
سپتامبر 15 22:59:30 linux systemd[1]: resume.service: Deactivated successfull>
سپتامبر 15 23:00:57 linux systemd[1]: Started Run commands after resume from >
سپتامبر 15 23:00:57 linux systemd[1]: resume.service: Deactivated successfull>
سپتامبر 15 23:04:02 linux systemd[1]: Started Run commands after resume from >
سپتامبر 15 23:04:02 linux systemd[1]: resume.service: Deactivated successfull>
سپتامبر 15 23:10:36 linux systemd[1]: Starting Run commands after resume from>
سپتامبر 15 23:10:36 linux systemd[1]: resume.service: Deactivated successfull>
سپتامبر 15 23:10:36 linux systemd[1]: Started Run commands after resume from
```

Comment: It seems to me that the service calls a shell script; once that shell script exits, there's no process running for the service any more, so systemd calls it "inactive". I don't know if those are recent timestamps for you, but the `systemctl status` output indicates that systemd is successfully invoking the service (script) and then marking it as inactive once it finishes. Is this a simple misunderstanding of what "inactive" means? (Separately, the service is "enabled")